# Django - Create href elements from a comma seperated list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, href

each of my post elements has multiple tags which are separated by a comma like so:

```
Tags: Peter Silver, Philippa, Politics, Sweden, October
```

Now I want a href element to my search function for every tag in that "list" so basically after each "," symbol. The problem now is that my tags are just a single CharField based String and not some kind of special field that could maybe manage this problem:

> tag = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tags", max_length=70, blank=False)

Can smb. help me out here?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting the tags into a list and then pass that as a context to your Django template to loop over.

```py
# Inside your view
obj = YourModel.objects.get(pk=1)
tags = obj.tags.split(", ")
context = { "model": obj, "tags": tags }
return render(request, "template.html", context=context)
```

```html
<!-- Inside your Django HTML template -->
{% for tag in tags %}
     <a href="/{{tag}}">{{ tag }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I Will try this solution later on but seems legit :D thanks so far, I will report back later on.